# Ajax call not passing any POST values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table that has sortable rows. The table is generated from a mysql database that has a field called "displayorder" that oders the table. When the user drags and drops rows, I want to use AJAX to submit those changes to the database whenever a user drops a row.

Currently, I can see the console.log() output from the success part of the AJAX call, and when  i output the data there (order) it looks great, like this:
`["order_1=1", "order_2=2", "order_4=3", "order_3=4"]`

But according to Firebug, all that's getting passed in the $_POST is "undeclared".
How do I access that order variable from my indexpage_order.php file?

I have this jquery code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var fixHelper = function(e, tr) {
            var $originals = tr.children();
            var $helper = tr.clone();
            $helper.children().each(function(index)
            {
              $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
            });
            return $helper;
        };
        var sortable = $("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //create an array with the new order
            order = $(this).find('input').map(function(index, obj) {
                var input = $(obj);
                input.val(index + 1);
                return input.attr('id') + '=' + (index + 1);
            });
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'indexpage_order.php',
                    data: order,
                error: function() {
                    console.log("Theres an error with AJAX");
                },
                success: function(order) {
                    console.log("Saved.");
                    console.log(order);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

indexpage_order.php contains:

```
if(isset($_POST) ) {

    while ( list($key, $value) = each($_POST) ) {
        $id = trim($key,'order_'); //trim off order_
        $sqlCommand = 
            "UPDATE indexpage 
             SET displayorder = '".$value."' 
             WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: most likely `order` isn't formatted properly. You sould be able to simply use `$(this).find('input').serialize()`

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(order)` and an appropriate point in your code and show us the results?

Comment: As a side note... It appears that you are attempting to use data from the `$_POST` super global directly in a SQL query. You should never use `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in SQL queries. This is a very easy target for SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should always sanitize data from the user before using it in a SQL query. Decent article on that: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/

Comment: console.log(order) is in "success" in the ajax call. It shows ["order_1=1", "order_2=2", "order_4=3", "order_3=4"]

Comment: @c.hill In my other files, I'm sanitizing with preg_replace. I'll add that in once the rest of the code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rewrite the js code that are generating the data for POST.

```
order = {}
$(this).find('input').map(function(index, obj)
  { 
    return order[this.id] = index;
  }
)
```

Rest should work in PHP.

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you for a simple, easy, concise answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try $_REQUEST instead of $_POST on the PHP file for POST method with ajax.

Comment: No change. I'm still getting the POST values listed in Firebug as "undefined" x4 and the Source is listed as "undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined="

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sending your order in a JavaScript array

And when it arrives at your PHP, its unreadable.

If its an object look into the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.
If its an array, serialize the data before it goes, then [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on the php side.

PHP is unable to understand JavaScript array or objects unless they are encoded/serialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

convert the js array `order` to json object as ajax data needs to be in json using `JSON.stringify`. hence, it needs to be `data:JSON.stringify(order),` in the ajax function.

Or, use `json_encode` like this `data: <?php echo json_encode(order); ?>,` in the ajax function

Answer (score 0):

`order` is an array. Convert the `order` to `query string` like this in your ajax script,

`data: order.join('&'),`

Comment: I tired this, and now I'm not getting any $_POST at all. The sorting still works, but I'm not getting the failure OR success messages from the AJAX call.

Comment: Can you do one thing, please put `alert(order)` before `$.ajax({` and tell me what you see in alert box